# Inverse of a function which contains an integration.

Tags: integration, functions

We are given a function $$Q(x) = \int^{\infty}_xf(t)dt$$

How do we find find $Q^{-1}$?

If such a question has already been asked please, comment the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to know more about the function $f$, I think. But perhaps someone knows a general approach. [edit: I don't know what I was thinking, but you certainly would need to know about $Q^{-1}$ to figure out the derivative.]

Comment: $Q(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\times \int_x^\infty e^{\frac{-{t^2}}2} dt$

Answer (score 1):

$$
Q(Q^{-1} (x)) = x \implies 1 = Q'(Q^{-1}(x)) \cdot (Q^{-1}(x))'
$$
So, as $Q'(x) = - \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{- \frac{x^2}{2} }$, if we denote $Q^{-1}(x)$ by $\xi(x)$ (for simplicity), we have
$$
- 2 \pi e^{\frac{ \xi^2 (x) }{2}} = \xi ' (x) .
$$
This looks like a rather challenging problem, as it involves solving a nonlinear ordinary differential equation of the first order; I will proceed to play around with this to manipulate it into a perhaps slightly less messy form (or maybe I am making it messier). Suppose that $\xi (x) = \sqrt{2 \ln g(x)}$, for some function $g$, (note that this only considers positive $\xi$, so that we should also consider negative values for the inverse, so perhaps a similar calculation as to what follows with $\xi (x) = - \sqrt{2 \ln g(x)}$) so that 
$$
- 2 \pi g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} ( \pm \sqrt{2 \ln g(x)}) = \pm \frac{ 2 g'(x) }{g(x) \sqrt{2 \ln g(x)}} .
$$ 
So finally, we wish to solve
$$
\pm \pi g^2 (x) \sqrt{2 \ln g(x)} = g'(x)
$$
This is a form of the Riccati differential equation (See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html)

A solution is found to be 
$$
g(x) = e^{ \text{erf}^{-1} \left( \frac{C \pm 2 \sqrt{2} \pi x^{3/2}}{ 3 \sqrt{\pi} } \right)^2 }
$$
where erf$^{-1}$ is the inverse of the error function erf. So 
$$
Q^{-1} (x) 
= \xi (x) 
= \sqrt{2 \ln g(x)} 
= \sqrt{2} \text{ erf}^{-1} \frac{C \pm 2 \sqrt{2} \pi x^{3/2}}{ 3 \sqrt{\pi} } 
$$
is a possible inverse. The constant $C$ can be determined by choosing a point and evaluating it. That is, we know that for $x = 0$, 
$$
Q(0) 
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0} ^\infty e^{-t^2 /2} d t
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \int_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{-u^2} d u
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{2}
= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi} }
$$
so $C$ must be such that 
$$
Q^{-1} (\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi} }) = 0
\implies
0 = \sqrt{2} \text{ erf}^{-1} \frac{C \pm 2 \sqrt{2} \pi (\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi} })^{3/2}}{ 3 \sqrt{\pi} } .
$$
As $\text{erf }(0) = 0$, then 
$$
0 = \frac{C \pm 2 \sqrt{2} \pi (\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi} })^{3/2}}{ 3 \sqrt{\pi} } 
\implies
C = \pm \sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }} }
$$
where the sign choice depends on the domain of $Q$.

Note: the discrepancy in the previous calculation between the $2 \sqrt{2} \pi$ and $2 \sqrt{2\pi}$ terms suggests that I might have made a calculation error somewhere.